# Django - can't apply migration

Tags: django, migrate, mezzanine

I'm new to django development, I'm working with Mezzanine == 4.2.2 CMS and django == 1.8 .It was working fine before but from past 2 days it's giving me the following error when I apply migrations.

```
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Synchronize unmigrated apps: adminactions, raven_compat, staticfiles, boot, filebrowser_safe, djrill, sitemaps, compressor, django_countries, django_extensions, rest_framework, mailchimp, grappelli_safe, thumbnail, localflavor
  Apply all migrations: shop, core, redirects, generic, django_comments, sessions, admin, report_builder, twitter, galleries, swingtime, sites, auth, blog, brochure, contenttypes, conf, forms, cities_light, checkout, pages
Synchronizing apps without migrations:
  Creating tables...
    Running deferred SQL...
  Installing custom SQL...
Running migrations:
  Rendering model states...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 221, in handle
    executor.migrate(targets, plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 104, in migrate
    state = migration.mutate_state(state, preserve=do_run)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 83, in mutate_state
    operation.state_forwards(self.app_label, new_state)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 51, in state_forwards
    state.reload_model(app_label, self.model_name_lower)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 97, in reload_model
    related_models = get_related_models_recursive(old_model)
  File "/Users/VinayManeti/Documents/hedgehog_lab_projects/backend/venv/latest_gs/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/state.py", line 57, in get_related_models_recursive
    rel_app_label, rel_model_name = rel_mod._meta.app_label, rel_mod._meta.model_name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

Comment: Show us your models.

Comment: I have 160 tables, it's very huge file

Answer (score 0):

Maybe any of the related model referenced as ForeignKey before, is not exists now.
Make sure all related fields are configured properly.

Comment: Is there anyway to check unreferenced fields?

Comment: I don't know anyway to check unreferenced fields.